# No such module 'Koloda"

Tags: ios, swift

This seems like a no brainer but I am having difficulty finding the `Koloda` module in this [library](https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda) . I can't seem to find anyone else with a similar issue, so I feel like i'm doing something wrong on my end. I keep getting the error "No such module 'Koloda'". I am just trying to load their project to see how it works so haven't done anything with the files.

Comment: Try running the app even with the error. It should work fine. Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Tried running it and it didn't work. However, I am trying to run it on the simulator. Is it possible this could be the reason why it's not working?

Comment: It always helps to try it on a real device. Go ahead and try that and tell me what you get. By the way, I only told you to run it because I had the same error with except it said " No such module 'Parse'". When I run it, it worked fine. But yea, go ahead and try it on a real device and let me know

Comment: tried it on the device and worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two methods:

1. Try running the app even with the error. It should work fine.
2. It always helps to try it on a real device. Go ahead and try that and tell me what you get. By the way, I only told you to run it because I had the same error with except it said " No such module 'Parse'". When I run it, it worked fine. But yea, go ahead and try it on a real device.